# shell script with multiple flags and arguments

Tags: command-line, scripts

I'm trying to make a simple shell script that gets some arguments and outputting them on to the console. I tried searching on stackoverflow and aksubuntu but couldn't find any which answers my question.
How do I get multiple flags with arguments like myscript -I inputHere -o outputHere -w ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192249/how-do-i-parse-command-line-arguments-in-bash

Comment: And: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16483119/an-example-of-how-to-use-getopts-in-bash

Comment: thank you so much. I don't know how I couldn't find the answer on a popular question. thank you so much.